# Who has a hurt expression in "He looked at her with a hurt expression"?

Tags: meaning

There is a sentence like below.

He looked at her with a hurt expression.

I don't know whether he has a hurt expression or she (her) has a hurt expression.

Please, let me know!

Comment: In order for us to come to a definitive answer, some context would need to be provided - sometimes context is all. That apart, this seems to be a question better suited to the [ell.se] stack than here as it is of a rudimentary nature.

Comment: He has the hurt expression. This is a common phrasing.

Comment: thanks for your answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

The writer, by writing that he looked at her, implies that *his* expression might be relevant. So this would fit in with the writer saying, in the same clause, that *he* had a hurt expression.

A point of grammar also supports this: "with a hurt expression" is an adverbial phrase which may naturally modify the verb "looked". But admittedly this is not completely compelling evidence, because in another context that same phrase might modify a noun, e.g. "Looking around the room, he spotted a woman with a hurt expression".

But it's not possible to say this with complete confidence, given only that one sentence. Some additional context might make the matter clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that it might be different by additional context. By the way, most of them wrote simply that he has a hurt expressin. I got this sentence from dictionary, so there is no additional context.